# Image scale and CGaffinetransformation values applying Uiimageview Not Working

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform

using uipinchguesters i am getting scale and transform values like below code

```
-(void)Scale:(id)sender {

   if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
            _lastScale = 1.0;
        }

        CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (_lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);
        CGAffineTransform currentTransform = imgView.transform;
        CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
        imgView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES;

        [imgView setTransform:newTransform];
       // CGAffineTransform newtransform = imgView.transform;

        _lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];
        [self showOverlayWithFrame:imgView.frame];

        CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        transform=imgView.transform;

        NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transform));

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",scale] forKey:@"Scale"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
         setValue:NSStringFromCGAffineTransform(transform) forKey:@"Transform"];
 }
```

then After i am saving transform and scale values in nsuserdefaults....

and kill the application and again run it we can images same position......
 i am updating like this scale and tranform values

```
 CGRect frameValue = CGRectFromString(
                                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"frame"]);

    NSString *roatValue=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Rotation"];
    CGFloat rotation=[roatValue floatValue];

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform=CGAffineTransformFromString([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Transform"]);

    NSString *scaleValue=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"Scale"];
    CGFloat scale=[scaleValue floatValue];

    Last Session Rotation

    imgView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform,scale, scale);

    imgView.frame=frameValue;
```

Answer (score 2):

By setting the `frame`-property on a UIView, you will remove all transformations on the layer.

Use `bounds` and `position` instead if the view is transformed.

Haven't tested, but flipping the set-order might work:

```
imgView.frame = frameValue;
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);
```

Comment: i gave like this but some time is coming small image and some time giving big image this the code

Comment: imgView.frame=frameValue;
             imgView.transform=CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform,scale, scale);

Comment: next line also   imgView.transform=CGAffineTransformRotate(currentTransform, rotation);

Comment: Edit: realized you're using a currentTransform etc so my comment here wasnt correct

Comment: Hmm, make sure you call "[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];" when you've modified NSUserDefaults